# How to access the root component data from a child template in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Is is possible to access this.$root from within a template in VueJs ?**

Example:

```html
<template>
    <v-card elevation="this.$root.$refs.foo.cardElevation">
      Foo
    </v-card>
</template>
```

I know I can add a property in the data object and point that to $root.cardElevation, but since I'm going to have many components use this value I'd like to be able to access it directly from the template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think access to the root component in such a way is possible and also not the best approach, instead created a config file, imported it and had a data property get the desired config from the configuration file.